# Amazon Aurora using wrong indices suddenly

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

This is an Amazon Aurora instance.

I had a query that was doing fine and was using a index p_date(datetime) which has high cardinality.

But since last few days, the query takes ages. I looked at the Newrelic transaction log and found that a different index status(VARCHAR) is used instead which has very low cardinality.

By explaining the query, I can see it's using index intersection along with another key which also has low cardinality being the client id.

All indices were there since the beginning. We use the both p_date and status in where clause in most queries.

Is there any reason why the DB wanted to use this index suddenly? Nothing is changed in the Code, so the SQL query is same. However, the tables in question, I deleted large number of rows (9k-15k each from 3 tables) from them last week. Could they be a reason for that? I use random UUID as primary key on those tables.

Do I need to run "Analyze Table" or something like that? Shall I remove that Index?  Not sure if that will have any performance impact.

I kept the default DB parameter group for the DB instance. Is there any tuning needed to do there?

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always useless to have an index on a flag (such as `status`); I see you have a case where it is worse than useless.

Get rid of the `INDEX(status)`

Add `INDEX(status, p_date)` preferable in this order so that you can also do a date range.

("Index intersection" was the clue.)

`ANALYZE TABLE`, assuming it is `ENGINE=InnoDB`, is fast but rarely makes any difference.

Why "suddenly"?  The statistics change over time, mostly because of added data.

Comment: Thanks for that. That was done when creating the schema initially. It was only using it if it found the records quicker then using other index as there were not a suitable one to choose. I now added some composite index on the fields that matter in the query and got rid of those useless index :)